# Using VSCODE, adoption of on-the-fly changes made to a dependent Java project by another project deployed on Tomcat

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code, tomcat9

Working in **VSCODE**, I have a **Java web project** called **aapp**, which depends on another **standalone Java project** called **aapp_restapi**.

Both are **mavenized**. But **I don't use Spring Boot**.

What configurations can I carry out so that the **changes** I make to the Java sources of the standalone **aapp_restapi** project are taken into account **on the fly** by the **aapp** web project?

Specifically, since I don't use Spring Boot, is there a way to do it from the ***VSCODE configuration*** (*settings.json*), or from **Maven** (*pom.xml*)?

Ideally by getting the **Tomcat server** to automatically restart (or without the need to restart) taking the changes into account.

Answer (score 0):

##### The following methods are for your reference:

1. [**Depoly**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mkloubert.vs-deploy) extension may be useful, install it.

   [image]
2. Here is a simple maven project as an example.

   [image]
3. `compile` project in **MAVEN** panel

   [image]
4. After downloading the extension, add the following configuration in ***settings.json***.

   ```
       "deploy": {
           "packages": [
               {
                   "name": "frontend",
                   "description": "All files in webapp",
                   "files": [
                       "src/main/webapp/*",
                       "src/main/webapp/*/*",
                       "src/main/webapp/*.*",
                       "src/main/webapp/*/*.*",
                       "src/main/webapp/*/*/*.*",
                       "src/main/webapp/*/*/*/*.*",
                       "src/main/webapp/*/*/*/*/*.*",
                       "src/main/webapp/*/*/*/*/*",
                       "src/main/webapp/*/*/*/*/*/*.*",
                   ],
                   "exclude": [
                       "src/main/webapp/test/*"
                   ],
                   "deployOnSave": true,
                   "useTargetList": true,
                   "button": {
                       "text": "Deploy",
                       "tooltip": "Click here to deploy frontend to hotsite",
                       "targets": [ "HOTSITE" ]
                   },
               }
           ],
           "targets": [
               {
                   "type": "local",
                   "name": "HOTSITE",
                   "description": "A local folder",
                   "dir": "target/DETE/",
                   "mappings": [
                       {
                           "source": "src/main/webapp",
                           "isRegEx": false,
                           "target": "/"
                       }
                   ]
               }
           ]
       }
   ```
5. After the addition is complete, click the `Deploy` button that appears in the status bar below.

   [image]
6. Right-click on the tomcat server and select `Add Deployment`

   [image]
7. Select `Exploded`

   [image]
8. Select the **DETE** folder generated by just clicking `Deploy` in the explorer

   [image]
9. Type `http://localhost:8080/DETE` in the browser address bar and press Enter

   [image]

   *Or right-click on tomcat and select `Server Actions...` --> `Show in Browser...` --> `http://localhost:8080/DETE`*
10. Modify `.jsp` to add a line of content
    [image]
11. Refreshing the page shows the changed content.
    [image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the effort you have put into writing such a detailed answer. As soon as I have time I'll try it.

Comment: Ok, if you have time please let me know if it works.

Comment: I find 'Deploy (Reloaded)' extension. Do you recommend that one or 'Deploy' one?

Comment: I use the extension from the answer.

Comment: As I can see, the owner is the same, mkloubert. And both repositories have been archived. But the 'Reloaded' version seems to be more recent.

Comment: You can try any one.